# Cannot get Traefik to work on Centos 7.5 with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, centos, traefik

- Centos 7.5

I am trying to get Traefik installed in Kubernetes using the guide from [here](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/).

I performed the following:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/containous/traefik/master/examples/k8s/traefik-rbac.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/containous/traefik/master/examples/k8s/traefik-ds.yaml
```

and then checked my pods receiving the following:

```
kubectl --namespace=kube-system get pods

coredns-78fcdf6894-5bslk                      0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   626        2d
coredns-78fcdf6894-fxr28                      1/1       Running            627        2d
etcd-nw-h-cos7-n1.natiki                      1/1       Running            0          2d
kube-apiserver-nw-h-cos7-n1.natiki            1/1       Running            0          2d
kube-controller-manager-nw-h-cos7-n1.natiki   1/1       Running            0          2d
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-6t2j6                   1/1       Running            0          2d
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-gxpg5                   1/1       Running            0          2d
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-nf6bv                   1/1       Running            0          2d
kube-proxy-5n9lm                              1/1       Running            0          2d
kube-proxy-62kkp                              1/1       Running            0          2d
kube-proxy-t7dfq                              1/1       Running            0          2d
kube-scheduler-nw-h-cos7-n1.natiki            1/1       Running            0          2d
traefik-ingress-controller-7vbkz              1/1       Running            0          41m
traefik-ingress-controller-9qld7              1/1       Running            0          41m
```

Now as I understand it I should be able to do a basic http connection on the master node as: http://localhost and get to the Traefik dashboard however I get a page not found. Same if I try http://localhost:8001/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/default/services/traefik

I also tried to proxy the ingress as:

```
kubectl --namespace=kube-system port-forward traefik-ingress-controller-7vbkz 8080:8001
```

but when I access it that returns:

```
Handling connection for 8080
E0801 19:26:49.332072   12575 portforward.go:331] an error occurred forwarding 8080 -> 8001: error forwarding port 8001 to pod 46a5574cef4397d0d58c453883c91fc1df5eff94e68234587077f9a1c65d83b5, uid : exit status 1: 2018/08/01 19:26:49 socat[17624] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:8001, 16): Connection refused
```

My topology is as follows:

```
Master 10.99.99.101
Slave1 10.99.99.102
Slagve2 10.99.99.103
```

When I look at the ingress logs I see:

```
E0730 22:02:57.030684       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/apis/extensions/v1beta1/ingresses?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

It appears that traefik is trying to connect to 10.96.0.1? No idea why. Perhaps the CoreDNS is the issue because looking at the logs for that pod I see:

```
kubectl --namespace=kube-system logs coredns-78fcdf6894-5bslk

E0801 09:32:21.267810       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:313: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
E0801 09:32:21.267943       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:320: Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
E0801 09:32:21.268219       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:315: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

I am wondering if this has to do with my use of Flannel or something else? Can someone please help me as to how I get to the dashboard to display?

Comment: Have you checked why are coredns crashing? Can you post logs?

Comment: @Crou I am a bit of a noob at k8s. Can you tell me how to pull the necessary logs?

Comment: I recommend checking [docs](https://kubernetes-v1-4.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_logs/)

Comment: @Crou More info added.

Comment: I think you need to first fix the coredns. From what you have submitted, I can see that only 1 is working and both are restarting frequently.

Comment: I had the same issue, I think it might have been something to do with me using Vagrant and the VM's having multiple interfaces. There was some issue with coredns and flannel using the private interface. In the end I switched from flannel to weave networking and it worked.